# Should I avoid querying the database in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm sure the answer is yes. But how would I write this differently?

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('online_ads', array('id' => 20))->row()->size;
$ad_array = json_decode($query, TRUE);
$result = '';

foreach ($ad_array as $a):
    $query = $this->db->get_where('ad_sizes', array('id' => $a))->row();
    $result .= $query->name.' ';
endforeach;

echo $result;
```

Comment: You would probably do a join on online_ads and ad_sizes and this way you wouldn't have to loop on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a query to join online_ads and ad_sizes. Yes, you will have redundant data from the online_ads table, but if ad_sizes has large resultset, the net execution time will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this you could better build comma-separated string of ids and then run just one query using `IN`.

```
$ids = implode(',', $ad_array);
```

And execute the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

Another option is to use `JOIN` queries. In your case I would make a `JOIN`.